# Passing a class containing a StringBuilder from C# to ada

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, stringbuilder, ada

I'm working in Unity C#, trying to integrate with a dll written in ada. I need to pass a class containing strings and doubles to the dll for it to modify and return, but I get the following error:
"Type System.Text.StringBuilder which is passed to unmanaged code must have a StructLayout attribute."

Now, these classes already have a StructLayoutAttribute. And I can't put a StructLayout attribute on a Stringbuilder, Unity tells me it only works on classes and structs. Which makes me really confused about the error message, because it seems like it's asking me for something that's impossible?

```
public class controller : MonoBehavior{

    myClass student = new myClass();

    [DllImport ("my_dll", EntryPoint="myFunction@12")]
    public static extern void myFunction(myClass c);

    void Start(){
        myFunction (student);
    }
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, size=2)]
public class myClass {
    public double height = 0.0;
    public System.Text.StringBuilder name = new System.Text.StringBuilder(16);
}
```

Comment: You probably can’t put the StructLayoutAttribute on the System.Text.StringBuilder component of myClass because C# knows that the foreign code (in this case Ada, but I expect the same would be true of C) won’t have the slightest idea how to deal with it. Best to treat it as you would for C: pass an array of characters and its max length, get back the filled-in array and its actual length, perhaps.

Comment: I tried this:

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public char[] name;

but it didn't make any difference. Still the same error.

Comment: What is the type signature of Ada subprogram you want to call?

Comment: in ada, it's
    pragma Export (C, MyFunction, "MyFunction");

and you can see above how I declare it in C#.

Comment: That’s how it’s _exported_: how is it _declared_? Something like `procedure MyFunction (Name : ?????, Height : Long_Float);`.

Comment: procedure MyFunction (Input : in height; result: in out name);

looking at it again, I tried putting height first in the class declaration, but it dodn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Something about this definitely feels off. If your Ada DLL knows how to handle a System.Text.StringBuilder then that seems almost magical. You generally need to pass primitive types around when dealing with native libraries. Also, this Ada DLL is possibly not a native dll, which is what Mono is expecting to work with. See [Interop With Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) for more info on marshaling data.

Now lets assume that your Ada DLL is actually a native DLL. And it somehow knows what to do with a StringBuilder. You can possibly pass a void pointer to the memory address via IntPtr. But I highly doubt this would work. Most likely what you want to do is pass the actual string through:

```
public class controller : MonoBehavior{

    myClass student = new myClass();

    [DllImport ("my_dll", EntryPoint="myFunction@12")]
    public static extern void myFunction(myClass c);

    void Start(){
        student.name = "John Doe";
        myFunction (student);
    }
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, size=2)]
public class myClass {
    //The following MarshalAs may be unnecessary.
    [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string name;
    public double height = 0.0;
}
```

LPStr is a 'long pointer to a string'. The assumption is your Ada DLL will know what to do with that. If that doesn't work, then you can remove the MarshalAs and see if it likes it better that way.

This C function will take an input str that must be less than ~250 characters and returns a modified string. You'll see that it mallocs a string the size of sprintf's modified string and then strcopy's it. There is no corresponding free() because it will be freed by [mono as mentioned here.](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#strings-as-return-values)

```
  char* myFunction(char* input, double height)
  {
    char buffer[256];
    int n = sprintf(buffer, "%s -- %f", input, height);
    char* ret = (char*)malloc(n+1); // +1 for the newline
    strcopy(ret, buffer);
    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: Well, in all my research, (and in your link) it is indicated that since I'm trying to pass "name" as a blank buffer and have the dll fill it, it needs to be a stringbuilder. As I understand, this has to do with stringbuilders being of a fixed length.

When I try to pass a regular string, or marshal it, Unity crashes - as in the program closes and asks me if I want to send an error report. Running it as an executable, I can see the generated error log indicates an access violation in module Kernelbase.dll.

Comment: So I didn't even see the bit about special handling of StringBuilder in the link I sent you. :) Interesting! I am not familiar with that technique, and will see if I can create a test. Is the reason that unity crashes because you use the string after calling myFunction()? If that is the case then you need to malloc the char* before returning it (and it should be the return the value). In the link it says "the runtime will attempt to free the returned pointer." This will occur after you are done using the value. Updating the answer shortly with more info.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC C# marshals StringBuilder as char* by default when using PlatformInvoke features.  This is handy for interfacing with C call convention DLLs.  Some Ada compilers (especially the GCC one) might allow Ada libraries to be optimised for C call conventions.  The "almost magical" nature of this may in fact be true. :)

My suggestion: surround your C# call to the Ada functions with an unsafe{} block and fixed() your char array, then pass it to your Ada function, then drop out of the fixed block again after it returns.

I don't have a working copy of Visual Studio so I can't verify this.

(Edited to fix incorrect terminology)

Comment: I guess it's worth mentioning that the dll I'm working with is exporting its functions for C:

    pragma Export (C, MyFunction, "MyFunction");

I will look into the unsafe and lock ideas. I assume when you say to lock the array, you mean I should use a char array instead of a stringbuilder? I've already tried that like I mentioned above, and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I should have said "fixed" insead of lock, sorry. Look at the fixed() function and the unsafe{} constructs.  These will let you get strong control over the low level memory representation of the data in your char array.  Link to the fixed() statement documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx

Comment: There is a problem though: Ada string is not equivalent to char*. if said DLL uses native Ada strings then things become really complicated.